# How can i refer BooleanField from models to Templates

Tags: python, templates, view, model, boolean

Please for help!

****im making 2 models: Question and Answer** like this:**

......................................................................

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    time_pub = models.DateTimeField()
class Answer(models.Model):
    question_Answer = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    true_answer = models.BooleanField(default = False)
```

**and my Views.py like this:**
..........................................................................

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import random
# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    bocauhoi = Question.objects.all()
    rand = random.choice(bocauhoi)
    traloi = rand.answer_set.all()

    return render(request,"Piapp/index.html",{"random":rand,"tl":traloi})

def Result(request):
    kqua =Answer.true_answer()
    return render(request,"Piapp/result.html",{"kq":kqua})
```

............................................................................

***I want to check the Field: true_answer and print in new templates.
HOw can i handle: If true_answer = True: "Your Answer is True" and else: "Your Answer is Wrong" in template.
Please Help!***